# Google Actions SDK "Error: Unauthorized, Your client does not have permission to the requested URL" caused by use of conv.user.storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I'm trying to convert an existing Alexa app to Google Actions wherein I need to implement session and persistent data values. My understanding from https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/save-data is that conv.data and conv.user.storage are intended for this purpose. However, making any attempt to assign values to either results in the error "Error: Unauthorized, Your client does not have permission to the requested URL", and also a reference to the offending key which points to this in the firebase console log: https://us-central1-hello-world-e37ec.cloudfunctions.net/cf-p7ROQlBMjQId9Cws6XdJBA-name. Similar issues here in stackoverflow seem to indicate that I need to grant the appropriate function to all users, but I don't know which function is being called. I'm new to Google Actions, so apologies if  I'm overlooking something obvious. Code is very similar to the example offered on google's doc.

```js
const {conversation} = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = conversation();
...
app.handle('status', async conv => {
  conv.overwrite = false;
  if (conv.user.verificationStatus === 'VERIFIED') {
    conv.user.storage = {};
    conv.user.storage.sum = 69;
    conv.add(`Alright, I'll store that for next time. See you then.`);
  } else {
    conv.add(`I can't save that right now, but we can add ` +
      `new numbers next time!`);
  }  
});
```

Comment: Is this an issue with executing the webhook in general?

Comment: It executes; however, if lines: conv.user.storage = {}; conv.user.storage.sum = 69; are included, the above-referenced error is raised. If the lines are removed, no error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this issue. Appears that I was not in the correct area of documentation for the "conversation" object/app. Correct method is described here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks#read_and_write_storage.

Using my example

```js
app.handle('status', async conv => {
  conv.overwrite = false;
  if (conv.user.verificationStatus === 'VERIFIED') {
        conv.session.params.sum = 69;  //within session
        conv.user.params.sum = 100;     //across sessions
    conv.add(`Alright, I'll store that for next time. See you then.`);
  } else {
    conv.add(`I can't save that right now, but we can add ` +
      `new numbers next time!`);
  }  
});
```